# Cascade DELETE confusion for Associations

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using HIbernate 3.2.5. I have a one-to-many association between Dept and Training table. One dept is capable of taking more than one training.

```
<id name="deptId" type="integer" column="DEPT_ID">
      <generator class="assigned"></generator>
  </id>
  <property name="deptName">
      <column name="DEPT_NAME"></column>
  </property>
  <map name="trainingDetails" inverse="false" cascade="delete" lazy="false">
      <key column="DEPT_ID"></key>
      <map-key formula="ID" type="integer"></map-key>
      <one-to-many class="model.Training"/>
  </map>
```

When I try to delete an entry:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("trial.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Dept department = new Dept();
    department.setDeptId(2);        
    session.delete(department);
    session.flush();
    session.close();
```

I can see that for the child table an update query is getting printed in the console rather than a delete query:

```
update training set DEPT_ID=null where DEPT_ID=?
```

But since the cascade is `delete` hence the child table should also execute a `delete` operation rather than an `update` right?

Please let me know where is my mistake.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will do if you use cascade as `DELETE_ORPHAN` stating that child object can't exist standalone.

In addition, you are not loading the object graph before deleting. Perform delete as below:

```
SessionFactory sf = new Configuration().configure("trial.cfg.xml")
                                       .buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    //load the object before deleting
    Dept department = session.get(Dept.class, new Integer(2));
    session.delete(department);
    session.flush();
    session.close();
```

Comment: No, I tried but got the same result. Still `update` is getting executed rather than a `delete` on the child table.

Comment: @user182944 Updated the answer. Please try.

Comment: ok now both `delete` and `delete-orphan` are working. Is it because of the way I was loading the object? Please explain it in a bit details.

Comment: @user182944: 1. If you are not loading the object, it doesn't have the visibility. So that was definitely a problem. 2. Delete works in your example but delete_orphan become useful when you try removing the objects from child collection and persist the parent to delete the removed children e.g. if you wish to remove 3 out of 5 training sessions from department.